# How to call a specific plugin for binding

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to call the plugin at page http://briangrinstead.com/files/bindWithDelay/. The old code is:

```
td.prepend($('<input>', {
    id: 'DNY-Filter',
    onkeyup: 'filterDP(this)'
}));
```

I'm trying `$('#DNY-Filter').bindWithDelay("onkeyup",filterDP(this),200);` but no avail. What should be the correct way to use it?

Comment: Something like `$('#DNY-Filter').bindWithDelay("keyup", filterDP, 200);`?

Comment: I get and error: TypeError: e.nodeName is undefined and is pointing me to jquery.js

Comment: This is not easy without a code, but another suggestion is to wrap your filterDP function like this: `$('#DNY-Filter').bindWithDelay("keyup", function() { filterDP(this); }, 200);`. If this won't work, try putting a breakpoint in jquery on that error line and then use callstack to see, where the error originates from.

Comment: Could you please upvote it also? Trying to earn reputation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('#DNY-Filter').bindWithDelay("keyup", function() { filterDP(this); }, 200);
```